# How to save newValue on OnPreferenceChangeListener with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that the newValue has not been saved before true on `OnPreferenceChangeListener`.

I hope to save it manually, how can I do? Thanks!

```
 fun setPreference(){
        val chAutoRestore = preferenceManager.findPreference(getString(R.string.IsAutoRestore)) as CheckBoxPreference

        chAutoRestore.onPreferenceChangeListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
            logError( "Pref " + preference.key + " changed to " + newValue.toString())

            //Save newValue
            startOrStopScheduleRestore(mContext)
            true

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in Shared Preferences automatically, in xml:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_value"
        android:key="YOUR_KEY"
        android:title="@string/title"/>
```

to get the value, use:

```
getSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("YOUR_KEY", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me

```
val notificationPreference: SwitchPreferenceCompat? = findPreference("notifications")
notificationPreference!!.onPreferenceChangeListener =
    Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->

        // Manually save to Prefs
        Utilities().putPrefBoolean(preference.key, newValue as Boolean)

        // Reflect the newValue to Preference?
        true
    }
```